# how could i get the updated rows number in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch, and in a project I would like to know the updated row number in ElasticSearch.

After some search, I could not find the usable API, so could you help me with the problem?

---

the code snippet is as below:

IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest();
        indexRequest.source("locked", lockable, "modified_time", DateUtil.dateToString(new Date(), DateUtil.DEFAULT_DATETIME_FORMAT_SEP));
        UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder().withId(String.valueOf(workerType)).withClass(Worker.class).withIndexRequest(indexRequest).build();
        UpdateResponse updateResponse = elasticsearchTemplate.update(updateQuery);

Comment: What do you mean by `updated row number`.

Comment: the number of updated rows

Comment: What query are you running. Please give a bit more information